# Populating Leaflet Map Markers from From Either a SQL Query or VB.Net Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, vb.net, leaflet

I'm at a loss on how to do this and would really appreciate any insight..
Many of you have seen this JavaScript code snippet before on populating Leaflet map Markers..

```
 var planes = [
        ["Littleton", 39.61, -105.02],
        ["denver", 39.74, -104.99],
        ["aurora", 39.73, -104.8],
        ["golden", 39.77, -105.23],
    ];


    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([39.61, -105.02], 7);



    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);



    for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker([planes[i][1], planes[i][2]])
            .bindPopup(planes[i][0])
            .addTo(mymap);
    }
```

My question is.. How do I populate the Planes Array from a query from SQL Server query? I can pull the [Names], [Longitute],[Latitude] and populate a gridview from the results But I don't know enough about Javascript to populate the "Planes" Array in there from the SQL Query..(and thus display the markers from the result)
I'm using VB.NET (aspx) but I can translate from C# if you only have the answer in that language..

I hope my question is clear enough to understand, please let me know if you need me to re-explain my question in any way.. thanks for your help..

Comment: I assume those extra `*`'s at the begin and end of the code section are unintentional and can be removed?

Comment: Yes.. I accidentally added them while setting up the code snip..